# Solve the Rook's Round Trip

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

## The riddle

In yesterday's newspaper, I found a puzzle in which a Rook should start in the lower-left corner of a 12x12 checkerboard and then, during a round trip, visit each field exactly once except for a selection which must be avoided. The puzzle came with a picture that identified the fields to be avoided as black:

[image: Blank checkerboard]

After some minutes, I came up with a solution, that you can find [here.](https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtnkgtvhywkd)
(There's no pic of the solution because you might want to challenge yourself by solving it first...)

## The challenge

To write code that produces the same output as my code (that's in TikZ):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\def~{)rectangle++(,)(}\filldraw[step=1]grid(12,12)(8,0~4,~0,3~8,5~11,5~,8~11,9~2,10~4,11~7,11~,);\def~#1#2#3{)-|++(6-#1,4-#2)-|++(6-#3,4-}\draw[line width=2mm,red](.5,.5~1355~5353~5356~7540~7375~7575~7375~7373~7372~5555~5553~5552~7375~7373~7345~5355~5555~5355~5272~5395~5673~7373~7583~9555~7955~5555~8376);\fill[blue](.5,.5)circle(.3)}\end~
```

of the picture that shows the solution to the Rook's Round Trip. This is Code Golf!

## Requirement(s) for the In-/Output

- Use whatever language you want.
- From your output, be able to somehow produce the pixelwise
  exact same PNG as in the code section below.

PNG code

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

## Bonus imaginary internet points

- Write the code in TikZ
- Your TikZ-code should compile without any errors, warnings, and boxes.
- You should be able to produce a PNG-file with Overleaf that, when saved in the same dimensions, must be able to withstand a bitwise comparsion with my solution.

Comment: What are the exact requirements for output?

Comment: @Unrelated String: Thank you for asking this question. I will clarify above within the post.

Comment: @Joe85AC I edited the first paragraph in an attempt to make it easier to understand, please do [review the change](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/205501/revisions).

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: Thank you, these changes are perfect. There's seems to be quite a difference between native speakes and non-native speakers... ;-)

Comment: Requiring the output to be exactly the same as the image seems unnecessarily restrictive to me. What if there's another solution to this puzzle? Also, please consider allowing other languages to compete, I don't think many of us golf in TikZ.

Comment: After solving this, it seems like this puzzle has a unique solution. Great puzzle I must say.

Comment: The `,border=1cm` can be deleted right? Also `2mm` can be replaced by `6` which looks similar but I'm not sure it's exactly the same.

Comment: To reiterate the second part of @SurculoseSputum comment: would sure be a lot more fun for everybody if we could just solve this puzzle as a straight-up code-golf challenge. Maybe add a **Bonus imaginary internet points** section for  TikZ solutions that are shorter than yours. You could also post your answer as part of the competition! :-)

Comment: [Borderline dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204375/58974), other than the restrictive output format here.

Comment: @Surculose Sputum: The answer is unique, as you already found out.
For your personal coding pleasure, I'll change a couple of the rules :-)

Comment: @Noodle9 I'll iterate over the rules. :)

Comment: @79037662 The border was also part of the image in the newspaper, so I decided to include it in my TikZ. The `6` looks similar, but would compute to `2.11667mm`

Comment: @Joe85AC You should decide what the challenge is going to be and make it so. You can't leave in this state of being two challenges in one and thus not a well specified challenge.

Comment: @Noodle9 As I'm a Newbie, I'd appreciate your help to edit the challenge in a way that it becomes acceptable for the community. Please let me learn from you edits.

Comment: @Joe85AC I've attempted to refactor the question to address Noodle9's feedback. Feel free to roll it back if you disagree with any of the edits

Comment: @mathjunkie Great! This seems much better now. My next question will hopefully better right from the start!

Comment: @Joe85AC It was still really two challenges so I've made some more changes to your already altered post. Feel free to roll it back or make additional changes if you don't like what I've done.

Comment: @Noodle9 Wow, the challenge became even better now. It seems like the headline was still a major bummer. Thanks!

Comment: "when saved, must be able to withstand a bitwise comparison" -- compression does not produce the same results with different compressors and different settings (and not even necessarily produces the same results with the same compressor with the same settings), so this requirement restricts us to either storing a compressed raw .PNG file or programming in your own favorite environment.

Comment: Feedback on the question: this is all framed as the rook-solving problem, but ultimately, the goal is simply to generate a particular PNG string? IMHO it doesn't leave a lot of scope for creativity. Would be more interesting if the output just had to "closely resemble" the picture, without requiring pixel perfection or a particular image format.

Comment: I have an answer that doesn't *quite* beat yours : [https://rentry.co/fbtce](https://rentry.co/fbtce) :)

Comment: @SteveBennett Note that "from your output" you need to "somehow" produce a png. Your output can be a vector that, if you --later on, with some other tools -- clip, compress, upscale, downscale, rotate, will produce the pixelperfect PNG. This does not mean that your output HAS TO BE the PNG itself...

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Note that "from your output" you need to "somehow" produce a png. bitwise comparison is only for the TikZ version...

Comment: What is the `Note that "from your output" you need to "somehow" produce a png.` sentence supposed to mean? I do not understand it at all. None of "clip, compress, upscale, downscale, rotate" were mentioned in the question. "This does not mean that your output HAS TO BE the PNG itself" - the question quite clearly says it must be.

Comment: @Joe85AC Well, ok, but that doesn't change the fact that the whole "rook's tour puzzle" bit is a red herring. The problem is just "draw this picture, exactly as follows".

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>959</s>  <s>947</s> 937 bytes

-12 -10 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!

```c
#define Z g&&S(r,c+40,20,q,1)
#define W write(o
H=1402;y=4206;char*s="VDRMOSMWK[I^HaGcFeEgDiCkBlAnAo@p@q?r?s>t>u>u=v=w=w=w<x<x<x<x<x<x<x<x<x=w=w=w=v=v>u>t>t?s?r@q@pAoBmBlCjDhEfFdGbI_J]LYNUPPSJ",*I,d[]="\0o\20\x90\xef",*G=",&&* ,* ,&&*%* %&#%*%*,#,#,&*,*%*)) ) %*%#%*%#%*),*%*,*%*,*)))%*%#%*%#%#)%*%*,*) ,* %*%*%#%#,#%* %*%*,*,#,*),*%*%#%#,#)))%&# ,*,#,#)%&&&&#%# %&#";P[]={0,255,~0<<16,~0},o,C,u,v,i,j,r,c,q=60,z=100;S(a,b,w,h,X){for(h+=a;h/a;h--)for(C=b+w;C/b;)bcopy(P+X,I+h*y+C--*3,3);}main(g){I=memset(malloc(y*H),~0,y*H);for(W=open("a.png",33537),"\x89PNG\r\n\32\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0\5z\0\0\5z\b\2\0\0\0\xDCTSV\0Z\eNIDAT\b\35",43);++i<13;)for(j=0;j<12;8&Z)g=*G++%32,u=j++==5,v=i==7,S(r=i*z+i/7,c=j*z|j>6,z+u,z+v,0),g&&S(r+!v,c+1,98+u,98+v,3),1&Z,r+=40,g&2&&S(r,c,q,20,1),g&4&&S(r,c+40,q,20,1);for(r=61;r--;)S(1281-r,s[r*2]+q,s[r-~r]-q,0,2);for(r=H;r--;I+=W,I,y))*d=!r,W,d,6);W,"\xfc\xa3\xea\xe1\xe8\x93\274a\0\0\0\0IEND\256B`\x82",20);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJ7c5pAEP@/n4LgyHDc0vDwlcHznShpY52YxtRgW0RErIri2zT56nYR0@mUZW@X394ee7s/R/Yc53hMDNyhP3O5LucJQlsMwaEpBTQFFqCSD@/RDrcN/ZUrBh8aTE0pmrFnKU3JGM7IDqUl4x9r93df2nedT8/m94Zdd27ca6/mV39VJuVZOSjNS4tiWFwWVoV1Yc02bBtJfve/xDjGN7hvVVgVl8WwtCjNy0FlWplUx7XR9fBmUO@bP257n781v7Za7VseJBMGzz3GW0pgaYq1u0J1h4jXGQ@CIHGAL9qkxCWFRBItJFAECdAlhCMcYolYSYTFSgj5iydIMsaisyI3wiCRjD8gOjBOjfEoVUhwJxxTBXwQj/7OGy0s9QUbnE7Dm5LPqxk0rxBAFdawAR/GgCOABcsocGCqohht0YY@bGEET@RlGITiiDLbGF2iyjKJgCrr061RvewbpO8E873Yok9g0pG0p1VZlnTQifE6tf2Z6JEXk03d6dJdiVN7MgkccS81CJYAkTWi0zosmLszkbc/zmceD7qe1rMEeGuXu2o161ZozSxdw0U5SWg2avcnL314N31LO0d3tepD@9FSupbbNGvlBwzpaR5SWBClfl7VjdMFxkwxxnlVM3JCl3hMqlOa1DVYszGljKVhw3zGsoDsZL50oP5lFhw2lg6/x4UMHOgadQMKgZjB9GKDJFbhKocRXDZ4f1CFLoSUIbU9QTsTHSmOPFejvNQ/3D@jp2aELKMaoSwbpC2qWk6VQ1g@h5LWo4vIkd/CnrwAHOf79sZpt0lZB0zYEyIN2EUIHRhAhhidqI1Dx9rZOlLURlVRc0hZ3dKyKfvcNcW8btYsLZ2p/MSuazzWgwM8Hv8A)

Each position on the board is stored in the lower four nibbles of the characters of the string `G`. A zero means a black tile, otherwise each bit corresponds to one "arm" of a junction:

```c
 0
1 2
 3
```

So a ┌ junction would be stored as the bits 1100, for example.

We simply loop through the string and draw tiles accordingly. Care is taken to match the jankiness that occurs in the middle of the board (slightly wider tiles and therefore everything shifted down/right thenceforth).

Everything is drawn as filled rectangles. An empty tile is just a black rectangle with slightly smaller white rectangle painted over it.

The circle caused some headache; just the data for it takes almost as much as the data for the rest of the board. I tried some circle-drawing methods, but the circle is not symmetrical, so no luck.

Various CRCs and similar are hardcoded, since we will always output the same image.

Stores output to "a.png".

Comment: @ceilingcat Hm, getting "a.png  CRC error in chunk IDAT (computed 64aecef3, expected 00004945)" with that. Something to do with the wide-char, it looks like.

Comment: If you're using gcc on windows, try `-fno-short-wchar` and see if the `wchar_t*` literal works

Comment: [929 bytes](https://ideone.com/to0Iwx)

Comment: If the `wchar_t*` literal doesn't work, try this one `"\xfc\xa3\xea\xe1\xe8\x93\274a\0\0\0\0IEND\256B\`\x82"`

Comment: @ceilingcat No such luck on the wide-chars, but well on the second string.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 1900 bytes

```
"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"~ImportString~"Base64"
```

I tried to use the grid-board to my advantage, and it still probably would be, but the thicknesses of the lines seem to very by 1 px either way, making this a likely comparable solution in length.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>3864</s> <s>3846</s> <s>3832</s> 3815 bytes

I’m new, so I could use help shortening it. It outputs to a file in the same folder called i.png.

`from base64 import*
open('i','wb').write(b64decode("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"))`

I could use advice on shortening it. This is the first time I have ever done anything like this.

Comment: Would it be shorter to store the PNG in a bytestring directly, escaping all offending characters? (there's also `base64.b85encode` and `base64.b8decode`; these seem to be better than base64) Besides, you can remove `c.close()`, and the `with` statement seems unnecessary because the program will shortly exit and close everything anyway. You can also skip the definitions of `b` and `a` and simply use `c.write(a2b_base64("long_string"))`.

Comment: I removed c.close() and defining b and a, but on my editor it wouldn’t run without the with statement. I don’t know how to use the base64.decode(), but I can look it up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can rearrange everything a bit to cut it down to [3815 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1chKbE41cxEITO3IL@oRIsrvyA1T0M9TV1HvTxJXVOvvCizJFUjycwkJTU5PyVVQ0lPT09JU/P/fwA).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on cutting it! I didn’t change the import statement but I did cut the with statement. It didn’t produce a png when written to a file without an extension, or it could have been 4 bytes shorter.

Comment: @BardicWizard file name should be irrelevant, as the format is still PNG. You can check that by opening the file in any PNG viewer (or even web browser like Google Chrome). Also I'm not sure why you don't want to change the import statement, as it saves 1 byte.

Comment: I had the bytecount wrong last time, so I updated to use your version @SurculoseSputum. Thanks! I hadn’t thought about the extension and it was fine when saved to a file.